# Why do different variable names get different results（python2.7）?

Tags: python, for-loop

in this code:

```
results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def inner(y):
        return i
    results.append(inner)

for i in results:
    print i(None)
```

**the output is "function inner at 0x107dea668"**

if i *change **i** to other letter*, for example:

```
results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def inner(y):
        return i
    results.append(inner)

for j in results:
    print j(None)
```

**the output is "4"**

---

**Answer**

```
results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def inner(y):
        print "in inner:%s " % id(i)
        return i
    results.append(inner)

# i -> 4
for i in results:
    # i -> func inner
    print "i: %s" % i
    print "in loop: %s " % id(i)

    # func inner <===>  A
    # i == A  ->  return i -> return A, so when call funtion inner, will return itself
    # print "call: %s" % i(None)

    print "call: %s" % i(None)(None)(None)
    print "------------------------------"
```

i: function inner at 0x101344d70
in loop: 4315172208
in inner:4315172208
in inner:4315172208
in inner:4315172208
call: function inner at 0x101344d70

i: function inner at 0x101344de8
in loop: 4315172328
in inner:4315172328
in inner:4315172328
in inner:4315172328
call: function inner at 0x101344de8

i: function inner at 0x101344e60
in loop: 4315172448
in inner:4315172448
in inner:4315172448
in inner:4315172448
call: function inner at 0x101344e60

i: function inner at 0x101344ed8
in loop: 4315172568
in inner:4315172568
in inner:4315172568
in inner:4315172568
call: function inner at 0x101344ed8

Comment: you just met lazy evaluation of `i`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805800/generator-comprehension-different-output-from-list-comprehension

Comment: This is not related to lazy evaluation, it is a context issue. Lazy evaluation is about evaluating just when needed, not where.

Comment: yes,I think it was caused by delayed binding,it is a context issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `i` returned in the `inner` function keeps its value from the last context it was assigned.

If you debug the code, using a breakpoint inside `inner` function, picture will become clearer if select the previous frame/context (bottom left in figures) before calling the function.

When you use `i`, it is assigned inside the second `for`, so it will have a function as its value (highlighted in yellow in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Kmd.png)).

[image: Figure 1]

Now, if you use `j`, variable `i` will keep its last value from the previous context: the `for` over the list (Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtnwR.png)).

[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 3):

The `inner` function you have defined contains a free variable referring to the global variable `i`.  This is perhaps clearer in an example like this:

```
def inner(y):
    return i

i = 1
print inner(None)

i = 2
print inner(None)
```

which prints 1 and then 2

In your first example, at the time of the call to `inner`, `i` has the value which is the function and so that is what is printed when `i` (which is `inner`) is called.

In the second example, at the time of the call to `inner`, `i` has the value 4 and so that is what is printed when `j` (which is `inner`) is called.

A clear way to express what  you presumably wanted here is to use a partially evaluated function, as recommended in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223829/1295678). Another way is to use an enclosing function to create a closure.  Like this:

```
results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def outer(k):
        def inner(y):
            return k
        return inner
    results.append(outer(i))

for i in results:
    print i(None)
```

which will print 1 to 4 as presumably you want.

A little trick sometimes used in Python is to use the default value of a variable as a cell to contain a value:

```
results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def inner(y, i = i):
        return i
    results.append(inner)

for i in results:
    print i(None)
```

which also prints 1 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you use j in results, the variable i remains 4, due to after the first-loop, the i stays number 4;

But if you use i in results, i refer to functions stored inside of results. The i is not fixed until you start to call it. as @Jean-François Fabre said, lazy evaluation.

**Additionally**, if you wanna inner function to store each i when loop from 1-4, you should store i in the related **scope**, use **partial** function;

```
from functools import partial

results = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    def inner(i, y):
        return i


    results.append(partial(inner, i))

for i in results:
    print(i(None))
```

this will give you results of

```
1
2
3
4
```

which is more meaningful.