# Same code gives different output depends whether it has list comprehensions or generators

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, generator, list-comprehension

I am trying to clean this website and get every word. But using generators gives me more words than using lists. Also, these words are inconsistent. Sometimes I have more 1 words, sometimes none, sometimes more than 30 words. I have read about generators on python documentation and looked up some questions about generators. What i understand is it shouldn't differ. I don't understand what's going on underneath the hood. I am using python 3.6. Also I have read [Generator Comprehension different output from list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805800/generator-comprehension-different-output-from-list-comprehension) but I can't understand the situation.

This is first function with generators.

```
def text_cleaner1(website):
    '''
    This function just cleans up the raw html so that I can look at it.
    Inputs: a URL to investigate
    Outputs: Cleaned text only
    '''
    try:
        site = requests.get(url).text # Connect to the job posting
    except: 
        return   # Need this in case the website isn't there anymore or some other weird connection problem 

    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml") # Get the html from the site


    for script in soup_obj(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract() # Remove these two elements from the BS4 object

    text = soup_obj.get_text() # Get the text from this

    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines()) # break into lines

    print(type(lines))

    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  ")) # break multi-headlines into a line each

    print(type(chunks))

    def chunk_space(chunk):
        chunk_out = chunk + ' ' # Need to fix spacing issue
        return chunk_out  

    text = ''.join(chunk_space(chunk) for chunk in chunks if chunk).encode('utf-8') # Get rid of all blank lines and ends of line

    # Now clean out all of the unicode junk (this line works great!!!)


    try:
        text = text.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore') # Need this as some websites aren't formatted
    except:                                                            # in a way that this works, can occasionally throw
        return                                                         # an exception  

    text = str(text)

    text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z.+3]"," ", text)  # Now get rid of any terms that aren't words (include 3 for d3.js)
                                             # Also include + for C++


    text = text.lower().split()  # Go to lower case and split them apart


    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english")) # Filter out any stop words
    text = [w for w in text if not w in stop_words]



    text = set(text) # Last, just get the set of these. Ignore counts (we are just looking at whether a term existed
                            # or not on the website)

    return text
```

This is second function with list comprehensions.

```
def text_cleaner2(website):
    '''
    This function just cleans up the raw html so that I can look at it.
    Inputs: a URL to investigate
    Outputs: Cleaned text only
    '''
    try:
        site = requests.get(url).text # Connect to the job posting
    except: 
        return   # Need this in case the website isn't there anymore or some other weird connection problem 

    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml") # Get the html from the site


    for script in soup_obj(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract() # Remove these two elements from the BS4 object

    text = soup_obj.get_text() # Get the text from this

    lines = [line.strip() for line in text.splitlines()] # break into lines

    chunks = [phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  ")] # break multi-headlines into a line each

    def chunk_space(chunk):
        chunk_out = chunk + ' ' # Need to fix spacing issue
        return chunk_out  

    text = ''.join(chunk_space(chunk) for chunk in chunks if chunk).encode('utf-8') # Get rid of all blank lines and ends of line

    # Now clean out all of the unicode junk (this line works great!!!)


    try:
        text = text.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore') # Need this as some websites aren't formatted
    except:                                                            # in a way that this works, can occasionally throw
        return                                                         # an exception  

    text = str(text)

    text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z.+3]"," ", text)  # Now get rid of any terms that aren't words (include 3 for d3.js)
                                             # Also include + for C++


    text = text.lower().split()  # Go to lower case and split them apart


    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english")) # Filter out any stop words
    text = [w for w in text if not w in stop_words]



    text = set(text) # Last, just get the set of these. Ignore counts (we are just looking at whether a term existed
                            # or not on the website)

    return text
```

And this code give me different results randomly.

```
text_cleaner1("https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=02ecc871f377f959&fccid=c46d0116f6e69eae") - text_cleaner2("https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=02ecc871f377f959&fccid=c46d0116f6e69eae")
```

Comment: I ran code few times and always get the same results for both functions.

Comment: instead of using `chunk_space(chunk)` inside `"".join()` you could use space instead of empty string in `" ".join()`  ( `" here put space ".join()` )

Answer (score 0):

Generator is `"lazy"` - it doesn't execute code immediately but it executes it later when results will be needed. It means it doesn't get values from variables or functions immediately but it keeps references to variables and functions.

Example from link

```
all_configs = [
    {'a': 1, 'b':3},
    {'a': 2, 'b':2}
]
unique_keys = ['a','b']


for x in zip( *([c[k] for k in unique_keys] for c in all_configs) ):
    print(x)

print('---')
for x in zip( *((c[k] for k in unique_keys) for c in all_configs) ):
    print(list(x))
```

In generator there is `for` loop inside another `for` loop.

Internal generator gets reference to `c` instead of value in `c` and it will get value later.

Later (when it has to get results from generators) it starts execution with external generator `for c in all_configs`. When external generator is executed it loops and generates two internal geneartors which use reference to `c`, not value from `c`, but when it loops it also changes value in `c` - so finally you have "list" with two internal generators and `{'a': 2, 'b':2}` in `c`.

After that it executes internals generators which finally get value from `c` but in this moment `c` already has `{'a': 2, 'b':2}`.

---

BTW: there is similar problem with `lambda` in `for` loop when you use it with Buttons in `tkinter`.